# Can you call subprocess on an Android device with Python 3?

Tags: android, python-3.x, shell, subprocess, adb

So I am doing a project and I was wondering, I know Android runs on a Linux Kernel and I was going to ask if the subprocess module would work the same with Unix commands on an Android? I found android commands but I am not sure if it would let me use them with Subprocess?? Such as:

```
command = "adb pull (whatever file)"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Thank you I would appreciate it.

Comment: adb commands only work on PC side. So any process related action will happen on the PC side and not on Android side.

Comment: You can certainly run a subprocess from Python on any platform it supports, but of course, you can only run commands which are actually installed on the device.

Comment: You are a SUPERHERO! That is very interesting, as I don't normally work with Androids but that is amazing and gives me a lot of insight! Thank you for your help! I think I just have to see what will work on my friends phone really would be the best bet. Subprocess is an interesting module too I just wasn't sure if it was completely universal. Anyways, I appreciate your help. Hope you have a great weekend!!

Comment: You are wrong about thinking that Android running a Linux Kernel matter in this context. Subprocess module runs commands on your python side (i.e. PC) and is up to the specific command to do something on a different device.